# how to remove whitespace from bootstrap container row col divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap and I'm getting free space at the very left and right of my div instead
of
taking up the entire screen it looks like it's only taking up 99%

MY CODE:

```css
#social-links {
  background-color : #242424;
  /* border        : .5px solid white; */
  text-align       : center;
  color            : white;
  margin-bottom    : -16px;
  margin-top       : -9px;
  margin-left      : 0px;
  }
#social-links a {
  color   : white;
  display : block;
  width   : 100%;
  padding : 2px;
  }
#social-links a:hover {
  transition       : 3s;
  background-color : white;
  color            : black;
  text-align       : center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid border p-0 m-0 no-border">

<div class="row p-0 m-0">
    <div class="col-4 p-0 mx-0 " id="social-links">
      <a href="#">Discord</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-0 mx-0 " id="social-links">
      <a href="#">Instagram</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-0 mx-0 " id="social-links">
      <a href="#">Twitter</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: remove 2px padding from a tag in #social-links might help

Comment: removing 2px padding doesnt fix it

Comment: You are using the same ID three times in your HTML code. That's invalid HTML. Use a class instead.

Comment: you cant add a class in bootstrap it has to have class container row col for the grid system Johannes

Answer (score 0):

The apparent white-space comes from the default margin on the `body` element.

Also ~ you are using an ID three times, when an ID is unique to one HTML element. I changed `social-links` to a `class`.

```css
.social-links {
  background-color: #242424;
  /* border: .5px solid white; */
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: -16px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.social-links a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 2px;
}

.social-links a:hover {
  transition: 3s;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid border p-0 m-0 no-border">
  <div class="row p-0 m-0">
    <div class="col-4 p-0 mx-0 social-links"><a href="#">Discord</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-0 mx-0 social-links"><a href="#">Instagram</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 p-0 mx-0 social-links"><a href="#">Twitter</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit ~ add `body { margin: 0;}` to remove the default margin on the `body` element.

Answer (score -1):

i fixed it the problem was with class row margin and padding
FIXED:

Discord
                  Instagram
                  Twitter

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how you fixed your problem? That way other people also could profit from your investigation.